# blender 2.8 Smoke color change?

Tags: cycles-render-engine

new to blender 2.8. i never moved to 2.8 when it came out and now im hating myself for it.

my goal here is to change the color of the quick effects smoke in blender 2.8 in the cycles render engine. how would i do this? ive tried inserting keyframes for the colors of the smoke but they dont change. i think the reason this might be is because im using the HSV color picker instead of the RGB. If i select my smoke flow object then in the shader editor the only thing that pops up is the shader nodes for the material applied to the object itself. how do i edit the shader for the smoke color directly and not for the objects material?

thank you for the help!

Comment: When you use the quick effect Blender automatically creates a Principled Volume material for the domain. In the shader editor type in "color" for "Color Attribute". Don't use capital letter.

Comment: the shader editor shows the material for the domain yes. but would you know if there was a way to change the individual smoke flow color in the shader editor?

Comment: The color attribute is located in the inflow's smoke properties.